# Is it possible to use MAGENTO 2 API on MAGENTO 1.9?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, api

There already exist an API called customers/isEmailAvailable in Magento 2. I want to migrate that API to Magento 1.9.

I do not have an idea how can I achieve this functionality?

I've searched a lot but i did not find anything

Please help me.

Comment: Can you please explain how and where you can use this API?

Comment: That  API already exist on MAGENTO 2, i want to re-use it on MAGENTO 1.9, do you get me? Take a look at this:https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/admin-rest-api.html#operation/customerAccountManagementV1IsEmailAvailablePost

Comment: You can create own custom API and use it. Magento 1 does not provide that.